# Unwanted linebreak

Tags: html, css

I have an `absolute`-positioned element `#blah` in an `absoute`-positioned container.

The code here produces an **unwanted linebreak** :

```css
#container { position: absolute; }

#blah { 
    position: absolute;    
    max-width: 20em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="blah">Blah dqsd</div>
</div>
```

---

Of course, we could add `white-space: pre;`: **this would solve the linebreak** problem, but would make the `max-width: 20em;` **non working on Firefox** :(.

```css
#container { position: absolute; }

#blah { 
    position: absolute;    
    max-width: 20em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="blah">Blah WWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWW</div>
</div>
```

## Question :

**How to have no linebreak after the first word, but max-width still working on Firefox ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the width for absolutely positioned div, just setting max-width won't have a width anymore with absolute position and having `word-wrap: break-word` is causing you the issue:

```css
#container { position: absolute; width:100%}

#blah { 
    position: absolute;    
    max-width: 20em;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="blah">Blah dqsd Blah dqsd  Blah dqsd Blah dqsd Blah dqsd Blah dqsd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Waw! Thanks a lot! It even seems that `width: 100%;` is not needed for `#blah`, it is enough if we set it on `#container` (see http://jsfiddle.net/uj20m17L/)....
So this means that `whitespace:pre;` is not needed anymore ?

Comment: @Basj Yes, that's not needed.

Comment: Thanks @Bhojendra - C-Link Nepal. Now I have another related problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186957/virtually-infinite-container-infinite-width. :(

Answer (score 1):

Before anything, we can discuss the **reasons** why is it getting caused.

1. `position: absolute`: Absolutely positioned elements take the minimum width possible. In your case, it is the first word's length or the longest word's length.
2. `word-wrap: break-word`: Breaks the word possible in the first space!

The **solutions** for this issue are simple.

1. Setting a `width` will solve the issue.
2. Using `white-space: nowrap` will make sure that the text is not broken.

I wouldn't say this an issue, but this is the expected behaviour!

#### Snippet #1

```css
#container { position: absolute; width:100%}

#blah { 
  position: absolute;    
  max-width: 20em;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="blah">Blah dqsd Blah dqsd  Blah dqsd Blah dqsd Blah dqsd Blah dqsd</div>
</div>
```

#### Snippet #2

```css
#container { position: absolute; width:100%}

#blah { 
  position: absolute;    
  max-width: 20em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="blah">Blah dqsd Blah dqsd  Blah dqsd Blah dqsd Blah dqsd Blah dqsd</div>
</div>
```