# Line break because of container's size

Tags: html, css

In the following snippet code, how to make that `#blah`

- 1) **breaks line** when the `max-width` of `#blah` is exceeded (here 1600px)
- 2) doesn't **break line** when the width of container is exceeded (here 100%) => I want the text to continue on the (hidden) right part of the page ?

Using `white-space: pre-wrap;` makes that lines are broken both in cases 1) and 2).

Using `white-space: pre;` makes that lines are never broken.

---

```css
#container { position: relative;  width:100% }

#blah { 
    font-size: 100px;
    max-width: 1600px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="blah">Hahaha hahahah hah sdfds fdsf sd fds f sdf sd fs df sdf sd fs df sdf sd f sdf sd f sdf s df sd f dsf END</div>
</div>
```

Comment: again unclear with the fact...

Comment: So don't breakline if the window is less than 1600px? Use media queries

Comment: @Danko, no, I don't want to use media queries, I have chosen 1600 as an example, but it could be much more... It's for this project : http://bigpicture.bi/demo   with lots of text... I want each textbox to break line **if and only if** the textbox is greater than some max-width,    but I don't want to "breakline" if the text goes in the hidden page on the right ...

Answer (score 1):

`container`'s width needs to be greater than or equal to `blah`'s width.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths:

1. The tentative used width is calculated (without 'min-width' and 'max-width') following the rules under "Calculating widths and margins" above.
2. If the tentative used width is greater than 'max-width', the rules above are applied again, but this time using the computed value of 'max-width' as the computed value for 'width'.

Using your example:

1. The tentative used width is 100%, which is simply the width of the viewport.
2. The tentative used width is *not* greater than `max-width` (unless you have really high resolution).

That's why `max-width` is ignored.

I posted a jQuery solution to the problem at [Virtually infinite container (infinite width)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186957/virtually-infinite-container-infinite-width/27188360#27188360).

However, there's a much simpler solution to the problem.  Add a `width` style to `blah`, which matches `max-width`.  That way, `container` will automatically grow to fit.

### Snippet

```css
#container { 
  position: relative;  
}

#blah { 
  font-size: 100px;
  max-width: 1600px;
  width: 1600px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="blah">Hahaha hahahah hah sdfds fdsf sd fds f sdf sd fs df sdf sd fs df sdf sd f sdf sd f sdf s df sd f dsf END</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @RickHitchcock for this detailed answer. However I cannot use `width` because : the <div> is in fact a `contenteditable` one. And at the beginning, it's empty (so width should be `2px` or something like that at the beginning).  *I don't want that any empty textbox takes a big fixed width.* (my project is http://www.bigpicture.bi/demo, you'll understand why I don't want a fixed width for each new textbox).  But thanks a lot for your detailed answer! (If you have a few minutes, we can discuss here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65842/bigpicture )

Comment: Hey, that's beautiful.  And I understand why `width` won't work in your situation, and why you want an "infinite" width on `container`.

Comment: Since `container` *must* have a width in order for `max-width` to work for its children, you could increase the width of `container` during a scroll event.